# @ and * in bash loop

Tags: bash

I found the following two loops yield the same output. Can you help me to understand what the differences are between the `@` and `*` in this particular case?

```
#!/bin/bash

ips=(8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4)

for ip in ${ips[@]}; do
    echo $ip
done

for ip in ${ips[*]}; do
    echo $ip
done
```

They both yield the same result:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash Man page quote

> Any element of an array may be referenced using ${name[subscript]}.
>   The braces are required to avoid conflicts with pathname expansion. If
>   subscript is @ or * , the word expands to all members of name. **These
>   subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes**.
>
> IF the word is double-quoted, ${name[*]} expands to a single word with
>   the value of each array member separated by the first character of the
>   IFS special variable, and ${name[@]} expands each element of name to a
>   separate word.
>
> When there are no array members, ${name[@]} expands to nothing. If the double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the
>   expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of
>   the original word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined
>   with the last part of the original word.

**Which means:**

```
munai@munai-devops:~$ declare -a array
munai@munai-devops:~$ array=(1 2 3)
munai@munai-devops:~$ bakIFS=$IFS
munai@munai-devops:~$ IFS=","
munai@munai-devops:~$ echo "${array[*]}"
1,2,3
munai@munai-devops:~$ echo "${array[@]}"
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've notice, there is no difference between the two - that is when the arrays are not quoted.

`"${arr[*]}"` expands the array to one element, whereas
`"${arr[@]}"` expands each element but preserving whitespace (IFS).

The first array won't change but the second will have the output of:

```
8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Thanks @DarkHeart. It explained. So which is recommended to loop through an array?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen your  first example with double quotes (ie ") around the array.